# KIF 2.2 Test case for UIIMagePickerView is not working with iOS7

Tags: ios, testing, ios7, kif-framework, kif

I have written the test cases using KIF frameworks. Issue to get the image from gallery using UIIMagePicker View -
**OS version is 7.0+ and
KIF version is 2.2.**

I'm using below code line to fetch the image from the gallery:

```
[tester choosePhotoInAlbum:@"Saved Photos" atRow:1 column:1 ];
```

I'm able to reach till photo and "photo tap" is also being placed but than it should dismiss picker after that and that is not working. Please help..

Any help would be great help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just answered the same question here [How pick image on Albums - iOS testing KIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194311/how-pick-image-on-albums-ios-testing-kif/27247510#27247510)

I can't get `[tester choosePhotoInAlbum:]` to work either, but I'm using this right now:

```
[tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Camera Roll"];  //Album Name
[tester waitForTimeInterval:1];
[tester tapScreenAtPoint:CGPointMake(47, 150)];
[tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Choose"];
```