# How pick image on Albums - iOS testing KIF

Tags: ios, automated-tests, ios8.1, kif

Faced with this problem, when you select an image from the album comes not click on the image. At point pressure also occurs. What to do?

used:[tester choosePhotoInAlbum:@"Moments" atRow:0 column:0];
As well as:  [tester tapScreenAtPoint:CGPointMake(47, 150)];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to figure this out as well.

Solved it by adding a `[tester waitForTimeInterval:1]` before `[tester tapScreenAtPoint:CGPointMake(47, 150)]`

Like this:

```
[tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Camera Roll"];  //Album Name
[tester waitForTimeInterval:1];
[tester tapScreenAtPoint:CGPointMake(47, 150)];
[tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Choose"];
```